# Is there a way to bind something to submitbutton?

Tags: php, forms, button, atk4

Can I bind anything to submit button? If yes how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to the JavaScript submit event:

```js
$('form').submit(function() { 
    // do your stuff
}
```

This binds not to the submit button but to the submit event of the form (that hopefully contains the button).

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to add from php? You can make an ajax call inside this submit binding that calls you php script (if that was what you ment).

Answer (score 3):

Just use regular button

```
$b=$this->add('Button');
$b->js('click',array(
    $form->js()->submit(),  // submit form
    $otherelemen->js()->reload(),  // do some other action
    $b->js()->disable()          // disable button
));
```

Comment: wohohoooh, this is interesting! i didn't know js() can be passed an array of js() for second parameter.. this is a great way to avoid very deep nesting of `js(null, js(null, js(null, ..)))` i guess i'm still at the tip of the iceberg trying to understand how agiletoolkit works! :)

Comment: It wasn't added too long ago. http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/chains/multi